# Azul Zulu JDK 13.0.10 is not taking environment variable from project configuration

Tags: java, intellij-idea, jetbrains-ide, azul-zulu

I installed new Intellij of community edition.
While running my project which was compiled using default version java(Azul Zulu) comes with Intellij, it was not able to pick environment variables set for java project.

Also, with Oracle OpenJDK it did not worked.

Answer (score 0):

This has nothing to do with the JDK.

Open the Gradle settings:

[image]

Change `Build and run using` and `Run and test using` to `Intellij Idea`.

[image]